# SOAP call with query on result (SSRS, Sharepoint)

Tags: sql, xml, sharepoint, visual-studio-2005, reporting

I created a report in VS using a shared data source which is connected to a sharepoint list. In the report I created a dataset with a SOAP call to the data source so I get the result from the sharepoint list in a table.

this is the soap call

```
<Query>
<SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
<Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
  <Parameters>
     <Parameter Name="listName">
        <DefaultValue>{BD8D39B7-FA0B-491D-AC6F-EC9B0978E0CE}</DefaultValue>
     </Parameter> 
     <Parameter Name="viewName">
        <DefaultValue>{E2168426-804F-4836-9BE4-DC5F8D08A54F}</DefaultValue>
     </Parameter>
     <Parameter Name="rowLimit">
        <DefaultValue>9999</DefaultValue>
     </Parameter>   
  </Parameters>
</Method>   
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

THis works fine, I have a result which I can show in a report, but I want to have the ability to select a parameter to filter the result on. I have created a parameter and when I preview the Report I see the dropdownbox which I can use to make a selection from the Title field, when I do this it still shows the first record, obviously it doens't work yet (DUH!) because I need to create a query *somewhere*, But! I have no idea where, I tried to include

```
   <Where>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name="ows_Title" />
     <Value Type="Text">testValue</Value>
    </Eq>
   </Where>
```

in the the soap request but it didn't worked... I've searched teh intarwebz but couldn't find any simliar problems... kinda stuck now...any thoughts on this?

*EDIT*

Here's the query I used according to the blogpost Alex Angas linked.

```
<Query>
   <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
   <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
<queryOptions></queryOptions> 
<query><Query> 

<Where> 

<Eq> 

<FieldRef Name="ows_Title"/> 

<Value Type="Text">someValue</Value> 

</Eq> 

</Where> 

</Query></query>   
      <Parameters>
         <Parameter Name="listName">
         <DefaultValue>{BD8D39B7-FA0B-491D-AC6F-EC9B0978E0CE}</DefaultValue>
     </Parameter> 
     <Parameter Name="viewName">
        <DefaultValue>{E2168426-804F-4836-9BE4-DC5F8D08A54F}</DefaultValue>
     </Parameter>
     <Parameter Name="rowLimit">
        <DefaultValue>9999</DefaultValue>
     </Parameter> 

  </Parameters>
</Method>   
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

I tried to put the new query statement in every possible way in the existing, but it doesn't work at all, I do not get an error though so the code is valid, but I still get an unfiltered list as return... *pulling my hair out here!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post at:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/1562bc7c-8348-441d-8b59-245d70c3d967/

Suggested using this syntax for placement of the <Query> node (this example is to retrieve the item with an ID of 1):

```
<Query>
  <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
  <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="listName">
        <DefaultValue>{CE7A4C2E-D03A-4AF3-BCA3-BA2A0ADCADC7}</DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="query" Type="xml">
        <DefaultValue>
          <Query>
            <Where>
              <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
                <Value Type="Integer">1</Value>
              </Eq>
            </Where>
          </Query>
        </DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
  </Method>
  <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

However this would give me the following error:

Failed to execute web request for the specified URL

With the following in the details:

Element &lt;Query&gt; of parameter query is missing or invalid

From looking at the SOAP message with Microsoft Network Monitor, it looks as though the <Query> node is getting escaped to &lt;Query&gt; etc, which is why it fails.

However, I was able to get this to work using the method described in Martin Kurek's response at:

http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dwise/archive/2007/11/28/connecting-sql-reporting-services-to-a-sharepoint-list-redux.aspx

So, I used this as my query:

```
<Query>
  <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
   <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
      <Parameters>
         <Parameter Name="listName">
            <DefaultValue>{CE7A4C2E-D03A-4AF3-BCA3-BA2A0ADCADC7}</DefaultValue>
         </Parameter>
         <Parameter Name="query" Type="xml">
        </Parameter>   
      </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

And then defined a parameter on the dataset named query, with the following value:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"/><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

I was also able to make my query dependent on a report parameter, by setting the query dataset parameter to the following expression:

```
="<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""ID""/><Value Type=""Integer"">" & 
Parameters!TaskID.Value & 
"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"
```

Answer (score 1):

See the question and answers for [GetListItems Webservice ignores my query filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835358). This shows you how (and how not to) set up your SOAP call to include a query. You probably need to wrap your query with another `<Query></Query>`.

Comment: Yeah, found information like that too, to bad it's not a format that works in VS when you use a Shared Data Source which is a SharePoint list., it only accepts the format I described in my post and I tried the extra <Query></Query> in that, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You have your **FieldRef** as

> ows_Title

I believe it should just be **Title**.

When you get results from the SOAP request all your field name will begin with

> **ows_**

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant, thanks. This solution worked for queryOptions also.

In the Query:

```
<Parameter Name="queryOptions" Type="xml">
</Parameter>
```

And in the parameters list of the dataset:

Name: queryOptions

Value: `<QueryOptions><Folder>Shared Documents/MyFolder</Folder></QueryOptions>`