# Followup to SOAP call with query on result (SSRS, Sharepoint)

Tags: xml, soap, sharepoint-2013, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a 2013 SharePoint site with SSRS that I am querying a large SharePoint list with folders that I want to query to just bring items back from a folder that I choose as a parameter.

I want to replace Folder A with a parameter. This query works if I put in an actual folder name, but I want the user to be able to specify the folder to bring back. My issue is the list is very large, so it does not bring all the data back unless I bring back only a subset of the data instead of the whole list I want to bring back on the one folder.

I just have not been able to get the syntax correct. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is an old post that is similar [SOAP call with query on result (SSRS, Sharepoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074529/soap-call-with-query-on-result-ssrs-sharepoint))

```
<Query> 
<SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
  <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="listName">
        <DefaultValue>FolderTest</DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="queryOptions" Type="xml">
        <DefaultValue>
          <QueryOptions>
            <Folder>http://portal.contoso.com/FolderTest/FolderA</Folder>
          </QueryOptions>
        </DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
  </Method>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```