# What is the correct SharePoint CAML query to retrieve all items from a list?

Tags: sharepoint, caml, suds

For some reason I am trying to query SharePoint 2007 using CAML and web services with the Python suds library. The call looks like:

```
listItems = client.service.GetListItems(
    listName, '', Raw('<Query />'), viewFields, 0, 
    Raw("""<QueryOptions>
       <IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
       </QueryOptions>"""), 
    None)
```

For some reason, I get 0 results or an error with `<Query/>` or `<Query><Where/></Query>` but get all items with a simple tautology `WHERE x = 1 OR x != 1`.

What is the correct way to just get all list items?

Answer (score 1):

To get all items, just put an orderby clause in there, and specify an arbitrary column. Should return everything...

Answer (score 1):

there is a silly thing about it, you have to wrap your `Query` within a `query` element. The resulting SOAP envelope looks like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
     <listName>TestQuery</listName>
     <query><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/>
      <Value Type='Text'>One</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
     </query>
     <viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRefName='Title'/>
  </ViewFields></viewFields><RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
 </GetListItems></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

As a result, the GetListItems web service decides that your query is wrong and returns no items.

See also this post: [GetListItems Webservice ignores my query filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835358/getlistitems-webservice-ignores-my-query-filter)

Comment: Good advice, but the suds library creates the `<query>` (lowercase) wrapper for me. Normal, non-empty `<Query>` (capitalized) queries work great. I will have to go into the debugger to verify suds has the same behaviour for the Raw('') of an empty string...

Answer (score 0):

You are using 0 for rowlimit parameter. Try something like 100.

Comment: I thought 0 meant 'no limit'.